# How can i target a click event to another component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have 2 components the main app.component and a header.component now I want to put a button in the header that toggles a class to be active in the main app.component Ive got the button working in the app.component but I want to move the button to the header component but with the same functionality

HTML

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary" 
(click)="togglesideBar(); toggleSign();">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{sign}}"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<!--Chat Side Bar-->
    <div id="chatsidebar" [ngClass]="{'active': isSideBarActive}">
        <app-chatsidebar></app-chatsidebar>
    </div>
</div>
```

APP.COMPONENT.TS

```
sign = 'chevron-right';

toggleSign() {
    if (this.sign === 'chevron-right') {
        this.sign = 'chevron-left';
    } else {
        this.sign = 'chevron-right';
    }
}

togglesideBar() {
    this.isSideBarActive = !this.isSideBarActive;
}
```

I tried putting the same functions in the header.component.ts and putting the same button in the header.component.html but it didnt seem to work

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Devin's answer below is one way to do this. Depending on how complex your app is though you may want to check out ngRx which is a more complex solution to this problem but solves many others as well.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyaAhXHhxgk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use events to communicate between components [see the angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

In your header component you can add an EventEmitter property to the class

```
@Output() sidebarToggled = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

then bind to the event in your main app component

```
<app-header (sidebarToggled)="onSidebarToggled($event)"></app-header>
```

and in the app.component.ts

```
onSidebarToggled(toggled: boolean) {
    ...
}
```

if this doesn't work for your situation you could also use a common service that gets injected into both components

Comment: Hey sorry, quick question now where do I put my functions??

Comment: the onSidebarToggled function should be in your app component class it will be passed the value of sidebarToggled when it changes from the header component. Inside the onSidebarToggled function you can toggle your isSidebarActive property

Comment: sorry so does that mean now on the button in the header instead of (click)="toggleSidebar();" i use (click)="sidebarToggled();" ?? thanks again

Comment: the name of the function is arbitrary. You can choose what to call it as long as the function name in your event binding matches the function name in your class. The button click event should set the EventEmitter sidebarToggled property to true or false. When it changes an event is fired that the app component listens for and toggles the isSidebarActive property

Comment: Thanks! just figured it out!